# Powering a raspberry pi 4 using a micro usb power supply with adapters

Tags: power

I previously owned a raspberry pi model 3b+ and have purchased a new raspberry pi 4b (4 gigabyte ram). I have an official micro USB power supply and some micro USB to USB type C converters designed to allow you to use old charging cables/accessories with modern smartphones.

I would like to know whether I can use the old power supply with the new board using these adapters?

I also won't be able to test this as it hasn't arrived in the post yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a micro USB to USB C adapter to power my Pi4B.  I used a 2 amp 5V wall-wart to provide the power.  Please be aware that I only use my Pi's headless so my current requirements may be less than yours.

[image]
[image]

I am currently powering the Pi4B via the 5V and ground pins on the expansion header (using a 5V UBEC powered from a 12V laptop PSU).